# surface area of cylindrical spiral

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, intuition

consider

$$\{(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi),\phi)|r \in (0,1), \phi \in (0,2\pi)\}.$$

is the surface area the same as that of the unit circle, that is $\pi$? Intuitively yes, maybe not :S

Comment: What do you mean by "surface area"? This curve is not closed.

Comment: for me it's rather a staircase than a curve, $r \in (0,1)$. am i wrong?

Comment: As it is written, to me it looks like a solid cylinder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the surface is that described by a radius having its endpoints at $P=(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi),\phi)$ and $Q=(0,0,\phi)$, then its area is given by
$$
\int \sqrt{dz^2+r^2d\phi^2}dr=
\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\phi\int_0^{1}\sqrt{1+r^2}\,dr=\pi(\sqrt{2}+\sinh^{-1}1).
$$
Intuitively it is quite obvious that the area cannot be that of a circle of unit radius: just think that by "stretching" your spiral by a different amount along $z$ you are changing the surface and its area.

Comment: @Quodly Beware there was a typo in my answer: it was $\sinh^{-1}$ and not $\sin^{-1}$. I've corrected now.

Comment: And of course $\sinh^{-1}1=\ln(1+\sqrt2)$.